# Unable to verify Token Contract

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, tokens

Having issues verifying my token contract on etherscan.io.

Receiving the following errors:
**Note: Contract was created during Txn#

Result: Does not match the input creation bytecode found at this address**

**Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI**

For some reason, the end of my Input Data does not give me a working Bytecode to use where others do.
Here's the transaction which made the contract: [0x49dcde944c36a473030ad9deccaeff062edae65957a3551c205f3b26315c63f8](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x49dcde944c36a473030ad9deccaeff062edae65957a3551c205f3b26315c63f8)

Any help is appreciated, I've been stuck at this point for some days, and completely clueless.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try again with this ABI `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000019d971e4fe8401e740000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000074172657869756d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034152580000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: Thanks so much! I I was trying this, but I think I also included some extra code from there.

Worked fine, cheers!